# Javascript clock to change hour, minute, second with image

Tags: javascript, image, clock

i'm confuse my clock not work

i have made pictures for hour, minute, second and am/pm

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zg00.png

i have tried this scripts

```
<script language="JavaScript1.1"> <!--

/* Live image clock III Written by Alon Gibli (http://www.angelfire.com/biz6/deathrowtech) Visit http://wsabstract.com for this script and more
*/

// Setting variables dig = new Image() dig[0] = '0.gif' dig[1] = '1.gif' dig[2] = '2.gif' dig[3] = '3.gif' dig[4] = '4.gif' dig[5] = '5.gif' dig[6] = '6.gif' dig[7] = '7.gif' dig[8] = '8.gif' dig[9] = '9.gif'

//writing images document.write('<table border=1 cellspacing=0 bgcolor="silver">') document.write('<tr><td><img src="0.gif" name="hrs1"></img>') document.write('<img src="0.gif" name="hrs2"></img>') document.write('<td><img src="col.gif"></img>') document.write('<td><img src="0.gif" name="mins1"></img>') document.write('<img src="0.gif" name="mins2"></img>') document.write('<td><img src="col.gif"></img>') document.write('<td><img src="0.gif" name="secs1"></img>') document.write('<img src="0.gif" name="secs2"></img>') document.write('<td><img src="am.gif" name="ampm"></img></table>')

//starting clock function function showTime() { now = new Date ampmtime = now.getHours() - 12 thisHrs = '' + now.getHours() + '' thisMin = '' + now.getMinutes() + '' thisSec = '' + now.getSeconds() + ''

if (thisHrs > 9) {   if (thisHrs >= 12) {
    document.ampm.src = 'pm.gif'
             if (thisHrs==12)
                    newHrs=''+12+''
    if (thisHrs > 12) {
      newHrs = '' + ampmtime + ''
    }
    if (newHrs <= 9) {
      document.hrs1.src = dig[0]
      document.hrs2.src = dig[newHrs.charAt(0)]
    }
    if (newHrs > 9) {
      document.hrs1.src = dig[newHrs.charAt(0)]
      document.hrs2.src = dig[newHrs.charAt(1)]
    }   }   else {
    document.ampm.src = 'am.gif'
    document.hrs1.src = dig[thisHrs.charAt(0)]
    document.hrs2.src = dig[thisHrs.charAt(1)]   } } if (thisHrs <= 9) {   document.ampm.src = 'am.gif'   if (thisHrs == 0) {
    document.hrs1.src = dig[1]
    document.hrs2.src = dig[2]   }   else {
    document.hrs1.src = dig[0]
    document.hrs2.src = dig[thisHrs.charAt(0)]   } } if (thisMin > 9) {   document.mins1.src = dig[thisMin.charAt(0)]   document.mins2.src = dig[thisMin.charAt(1)] } if (thisMin <= 9) {   document.mins1.src = dig[0]   document.mins2.src = dig[thisMin.charAt(0)] } if (thisSec > 9) {   document.secs1.src = dig[thisSec.charAt(0)]   document.secs2.src = dig[thisSec.charAt(1)] } if (thisSec <= 9) {   document.secs1.src = dig[0]   document.secs2.src = dig[thisSec.charAt(0)] } setTimeout("showTime()",1000) }

window.onload=showTime // --> </script>
```

how to change every hour,minute, second and am/pm with images i have made?

i have tried many ways but failed :(

thank you :)

Comment: **word of caution:** if your example `<script>` tag contains a language attribute or wraps script in `<!-- html comments -->` then it's a safe bet that you haven't stumbled upon a good source for code.

Comment: Can you upload your images somewhere so we can play around with them - this is a situation where we'd be better giving you a nice example rather than kludging bad code.

Comment: woooow thanks a lot guys, i will upload my images

Comment: this is my images

http://db.tt/SEWCbHAV

thanks a loooot :')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordinarily I'd approach this with a [sprite sheet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_sheet) in mind as you have 135 unique images and traditionally that would mean 135 requests to a web server which would result in poor performance.  Technically your images are simple enough that the effect could be generated using CSS or SVG quite easily too...

However because that feels like cheating the question and because you haven't specified a particular size for your clock; I've stuck with a solution using individual images - though I have taken measures to optimise your images for this example which I will explain first.

---

The images in your zip file are `400x298` pixels totalling 4MB (this is arguably ***not*** web-friendly) and if you can't resize them (*IE*. you actually want a big clock) then you should consider compressing the images.  For the sake of this example and other people's bandwidth I've reduced the images to `50x37` and compressed them using [pngquant](http://pngquant.org/) (highly recommend checking this out).

I've also [base64-encoded](https://www.google.com/search?q=base64+encode+images) the images and dumped them in a javascript object that looks like so:

```
Clock.prototype.imgs = {
    hrs:[...], // array(13)
    min:[...], // array(60)
    sec:[...], // array(60)
    gmt:[...]  // array(2)
}
```

This means that all the images can be loaded into the page in a single request and understood by the browser by means of a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

<sup>*All in all file-size cut down to ~150KB :)*</sup>

---

And so to the script: (I've tried to keep it as straight-forward as possible)

First you need to leave an element in the page to hook on to, eg:

```
<div id="myClock"></div>
```

and then in your script tags:

```
new Clock;
function Clock(){

    // setup our DOM elements
    var clock = document.getElementById('myClock');
    this.elHrs = document.createElement('img');
    this.elMin = document.createElement('img');
    this.elSec = document.createElement('img');
    this.elGmt = document.createElement('img'); 
    clock.appendChild(this.elHrs);
    clock.appendChild(this.elMin);
    clock.appendChild(this.elSec);
    clock.appendChild(this.elGmt);

    // set a timer to update every second
    this.tick = setInterval((function(scope){
        return function(){ scope.draw(); }
    })(this), 1000);

    this.draw = function(){
        var date = new Date,
            gmt  = Math.floor(date.getHours()/12),
            hrs  = date.getHours(),
            min  = date.getMinutes(),
            sec  = date.getSeconds(),
            uri  = 'data:image/png;base64,';
        if(hrs!=12) hrs %= 12;
        this.elHrs.src = uri + this.imgs.hrs[hrs];
        this.elMin.src = uri + this.imgs.min[min];
        this.elSec.src = uri + this.imgs.sec[sec];
        this.elGmt.src = uri + this.imgs.gmt[gmt];        
    }
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/w6uZR/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(() => {
  d = new Date();
  htime = d.getHours();
  mtime = d.getMinutes();
  stime = d.getSeconds();
  hrotation = 30 * htime + mtime / 2;
  mrotation = 6 * mtime;
  srotation = 6 * stime;

  hour.style.transform = `rotate(${hrotation}deg)`;
  minute.style.transform = `rotate(${mrotation}deg)`;
  second.style.transform = `rotate(${srotation}deg)`;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.